# How to define some configuration variables

Tags: c++

As the title indicates, 
I have to read some values from XML file and use this values in different classes which are in different files.

Which way should I use to define these variables?

Should I use a class to hold these variables,
Should I use a namespace to hold these variables,
Should I define them as static global variables (if it is possible)

In java I would just define them as public static variables and use class.XX to access them, but in c++ this does not work I think.

Comment: It's a very opinion-based question!

Comment: I would create a wrapper class that reads the configuration parameters from the XML files.
This wrapper class can have static methods to read each parameter value.

Comment: @RamiHelmy Thanks for the answer. Sounds like good idea to use a wrapper class.

Comment: @MM.What do you mean by that comment? So what if it is a opinion based question? This is not a place to discuss about opinions?